# Multicast Support in Android 2.2?

Tags: android, multicast, android-2.2-froyo

Does the Android 2.2 media framework support IGMP/Multicast? If yes, can anyone guide how we can do that?

Comment: Can't put this as an answer, since I don't have any resources to currently back me up.  However, it is my understanding that there is no support for IGMP/Multicast in Android 2.2.  I looked into it in August and found nothing supporting the claim that multicast worked in Android 2.2, and a LOT supporting the opposite, that there is NO multicast support.
Not what you wanted to hear, I'm sure, but that's the impression I've been under.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple:

1. Inform the wifimanager that your app need to receive multicast:

   ```
   WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService( Context.WIFI_SERVICE );
   MulticastLock mcLock = wifi.createMulticastLock("mylock");
   mcLock.acquire();
   ```
2. Create the socket:

   ```
   InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(MULTICAST_ADDRESS);
   MulticastSocket s = new MulticastSocket(MULTICAST_PORT);
   s.joinGroup(group);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Multicast support in Android is not as solid as some of use might hope. See http://codeisland.org/2012/udp-multicast-on-android/

Ie whether it actually works out or may be device dependent. It is not working on my Nexus5.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=51195